# Can modifying environment variables in Windows cause vulnerability?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

As normal user, if you open the `Edit Environment Variable` setting in Windows, you will get this:

[image: environment variables]

As you can see, the `%path%` variable that available for an user is a combination of `%path%` set globally as `System variables` and `%path%` set locally for each user `User variables for username`.

Consider the following situation:

If the user adds a path to his `User variables` `%path%`, for example he adds `C:\mybin` to his `User variables` `%path%` to run his program `myapp.exe` in `C:\mybin\myapp.exe`. But if he accidentally runs an unwanted program (as normal user) that change his user `%path%` (this [can be done](https://superuser.com/a/79614/1320899) **without** administrator rights) to a different directory, for example `%temp%\fake` which contain the fake app but same name `myapp.exe` and delete the path `C:\mybin` from his variable, then he open Command Prompt as Administrator to run his `myapp.exe`, he will get the fake app `myapp.exe` run as administrator.

So my question is: is this called a vulnerability and will it be practical for viruses to do this?

I also find that some installers (which are run as administrator), extract their contents to `%temp%` and run some of these, so is they vulnerable too?

Thanks!

Comment: If a virus could do all that, then why not simply replace the existing binary with the malicious one?

Comment: But what if the existing binary is in a write-protected directory?

Comment: I think if there is any virus do this, it will run the user's expected program. When it doesn't have admin rights, and when it has the admin rights it will go ahead and do its stubs

Comment: Wouldn't a malware attacking the PATH variable be targeted for command line users, where the search path has some effect. A typical Windows user doesn't start programs from command line, but from icons on the start menu and the desktop.

Comment: But if a malware could do any of this, it could also do more beneficial changes to gain persistence that doesn't require any actions from the user.

Comment: Can you show me how?

Comment: Take a look at, e.g., [Windows Userland Persistence Fundamentals](https://www.fuzzysecurity.com/tutorials/19.html).